# Выдает ошибку Notice: Undefined variable: plugins/Reputation/ReputationController.class.php

Tags: php

```
    if (!defined("IN_ESOTALK")) exit;

class ReputationController extends ETController {

    public function action_index($orderBy = false, $start = 0)
    {
        if (!$this->allowed("esoTalk.members.visibleToGuests")) return;
        //If admin has disabled reputatoin points, break
        if(!C("plugin.Reputation.showReputationPublic")) return;
        $model = ET::getInstance("reputationModel");
        $members = $model->getReputationMembers();

    
        $rank = $model->getRankOfCurrentMember(ET::$session->userId, $members);
        //Three parameters for getNearbyReputationMembers is number of members to be shown, offset, members array
        if($rank>10) $nearbyMembers = $model->getNearbyReputationMembers(10, $rank-5, $members);

        //Get top 10 reputation members
        $topMembers = $model->getTopReputationMembers(10, $members);
        

        $this->data("topMembers",$topMembers);
        $this->data("nearbyMembers",$nearbyMembers);  # ошибка возникает здесь !!!
        $this->data("rank",$rank);

        $this->render("reputation");
    }

}
```

Выдаёт ошибку:
Notice: Undefined variable: dic in ../public_html/addons/plugins/Reputation/ReputationController.class.php on line 36

Подскажите как исправить. Указывает на эту строку $this->data("nearbyMembers",$nearbyMembers);

Версия PHP 5.6.40

Comment: так, к слову: notice — это не ошибка. ошибка — это error.

Comment: в приведённом коде нет переменой `dic`. Наверное как и вообще в коде))